# how can I make a field's value one hundredth of what is actually entered?

Tags: javascript, html, function, math, button

Currently, when you click the submit button, it'll multiply the number in the first field by the number in the second field.

**What I want is to get the number in the second field to calculate as 1/100th of whatever the user enters.**

For example, if you were to enter 1000 in the first field, and 6 in the second field, then the calculation would execute as 1000 * 0.06 instead of 1000 * 6, resulting in 60 instead of 6000.

I ask because simply entering in 0.0X in the second field causes the answer to be zero, which is obviously incorrect.

Except, I have no idea what I need to write to get it to work. What can I add/change in my JavaScript?

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numberOne = document.getElementById('numberOne').value;
    const numberTwo = document.getElementById('numberTwo').value;
    const mathSolution = parseInt(numberOne) * parseInt(numberTwo);
    
    alert("The solution is... " + mathSolution);

});
```

```html
<h2>Enter a number</h2>
<input type="number" id="numberOne">
                                                
<h2>Enter another number</h2>
<input type="number" id="numberTwo">

<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dive 6 by 100 you get .06 if you parseInt that you get 0.  But the good news is you don't need  integers!

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numberOne = document.getElementById('numberOne').value;
    const numberTwo = document.getElementById('numberTwo').value / 100;
    const mathSolution = numberOne * numberTwo;
    
    alert("The solution is... " + mathSolution);

});
```

```html
<h2>Enter a number</h2>
<input type="number" id="numberOne">
                                                
<h2>Enter another number</h2>
<input type="number" id="numberTwo">

<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: While you'll still need `parseFloat(number)`, the math works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line: `const mathSolution = parseInt(numberOne) * parseInt(numberTwo);` to `const mathSolution = parseFloat(numberOne) * parseFloat(numberTwo);` 
Otherwise you are working with integers only and 0.x ends up as 0.

Answer (score 0):

As @DCR has already answered to this question, You can also use a one-liner like this:

```js
document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click',()=>alert("The solution is... "+document.getElementById('numberTwo').value*(document.getElementById('numberOne').value)/100));
```

```html
<h2>Enter a number</h2>
<input type="number" id="numberOne">      
                                     
<h2>Enter another number</h2>
<input type="number" id="numberTwo">

<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Calculate</button>
```